# How do I fix distortion in Render?

Tags: rendering, video

My render shows a horizontal line distortion during playback. Increasing the render samples to 500 did not improve the quality at all. How can I make it smooth throughout?

[Animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvei3ywwsh9zmsl/0001-0190.avi?dl=0)

[Blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8sehr7ffyvqkdz/simpleinto.blend?dl=0)

Comment: I can't see anything the matter with it . . .

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like a problem occurring during playback, it's not part of the file.

The distortion is inconsistent between playbacks, and I've only seen it (sometimes) when using VLC. mplayer has no problems.

I don't know if there is anything you can do, this looks like a problem with the program doing the decoding.